# Remember me checbox doesn't work in Yii2

Tags: checkbox, yii2

Somehow, my login's page `remember me` checkbox doesn't remember any of the user's enetered information. When I load the page, the `Remember me` checkbox is marked automatically, after I enter my `email` and `password`, next time it does not remember any of the information. Could someone tell me why? Thank you for any help.

Model function:

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
public $email;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;

 /**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`View` file:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe', [
    'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
])->checkbox() ?>
```

Controller's `actionLogin()`:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the remember me checkbox in the user login page is not to store username/password fields and autocomplete them, that is done by the browser. It purpose is to maintain the session active even though the browser window is closed, so that when you open it again and go to the site, you are already logged in.

Comment: Ok, but the code still doesnt' work and I've no idea what's wrong

Comment: The code seems okay, you have to see the value of rememberMe that gets through the form.